# Using C5 Collection Tree Data Structure

Tags: c#, data-structures, c5

I have been struggling for days finding .NET `Tree Data Structure`, I have read many recomendation using [C5 library](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/), but I have yet find example for it.

[image: Basic Tree]

I have read C5 documentation but didn't find example for it (I admit I haven't read all documentation page).

`Edit: I need a Tree with basic functionality like search from parent to child node and vice versa.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need the most basic functionality, then build your own data structure.

I did a quick implementation of a basic tree (directional edges and not necessarily binary tree), assuming you have a fixed root node. I also added methods for searching depth first and breadth first.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace TreeTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Build example tree
            Tree tree = new Tree();
            Node a = new Node(2);
            Node b = new Node(7);
            Node c = new Node(2);
            Node d = new Node(6);
            Node e = new Node(5);
            Node f = new Node(11);
            Node g = new Node(5);
            Node h = new Node(9);
            Node i = new Node(4);

            tree.rootNode = a;
            a.Edges.Add(b);
            b.Edges.Add(c);
            b.Edges.Add(d);
            d.Edges.Add(e);
            d.Edges.Add(f);
            a.Edges.Add(g);
            g.Edges.Add(h);
            h.Edges.Add(i);

            //Find node scannin tree from top down
            Node node = tree.FindByValueBreadthFirst(6);
            Console.WriteLine(node != null ? "Found node" : "Did not find node");

            //Find node scanning tree branch for branch.
            node = tree.FindByValueDepthFirst(2);
            Console.WriteLine(node != null ? "Found node" : "Did not find node");

            Console.WriteLine("PRESS ANY KEY TO EXIT");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
    class Tree
    {
        public Node rootNode;
        public Node FindByValueDepthFirst(int val)
        {
            return rootNode.FindRecursiveDepthFirst(val);
        }
        public Node FindByValueBreadthFirst(int val)
        {
            if (rootNode.Value == val)
                return rootNode;
            else
                return rootNode.FindRecursiveBreadthFirst(val);
        }
    }
    class Node
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
        public IList<Node> Edges { get; set; }
        public Node(int val)
        {
            Value = val;
            Edges = new List<Node>(2);
        }
        public Node FindRecursiveBreadthFirst(int val)
        {
            foreach (Node node in Edges)
            {
                if (node.Value == val)
                    return node;
            }
            foreach (Node node in Edges)
            {
                Node result = node.FindRecursiveBreadthFirst(val);
                if (result != null)
                    return result;
            }
            return null;
        }
        public Node FindRecursiveDepthFirst(int val)
        {
            if (Value == val)
                return this;
            else
            {
                foreach (Node node in Edges)
                {
                    Node result = node.FindRecursiveDepthFirst(val);
                    if (result != null)
                        return result;
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Kjetil,exactly what i was looking for  (Y)

Answer (score 2):

If you need **only** tree datastructure, just define yours. (will loose less time)

```
public abstract class NodeAbstract
{
   abstract NodeAbstract Left {get;set:}
   abstract NodeAbstract Right {get;set:}
   .... 
   ....
}

public class NodeConcrete : NodeAbstract
{

   .... 
   //implementation
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can you elaborate your answer more ?

Comment: @CodingJunkies: what do you mean ? My answer is in short: if you need **only** tree like data holder, use your own. But if you need some tree traversal algos (say), your datastacture in this case can become uselss, so you should cosider some extrnal framework like that one mantioned by you.

Comment: I need some basic functionality like searching from parent to child node and and vice versa.

Comment: @CodingJunkies: I think [Building Better Binary Search Tree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379573(v=vs.80).aspx) is something you need, in this case.